# PayPal API Response how to get the response javascript function changed to PHP variables?

Tags: javascript, php, api, paypal

hope you can help!

Just testing the PayPal API in sandbox at the moment, i'm creating and authorising the payment ok and this returns an alert to the page with info from the payer, this is in javascript, what i want to do is remove the alert message showing the details and instead, use the payer details to show a message and update my database using PHP.

How can i get the details showing in the javascript alert below back into usable PHP variables i can send to my database to update it and show the approved message?

At the moment: `details.payer.email_address` shows the email address correctly but i want to get this into a php veriable like `$email = details.payer.email_address;`

```
 <script
    src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Af_V3NNV2RUksS5sfObGCirO3gTXSFuetygoYta5-zU-ROGToia5dceU9cT5DBL821zc-ihtNQydiqsf&currency=GBP&intent=capture&disable-funding=card,bancontact,sepa,ideal,sofort" data-order-id="2VW94544JM6797511">
  </script>

    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '25.20'
          }
        }]

      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      // Capture the funds from the transaction
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // Show a success message to your buyer
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + ' ' + details.payer.name.surname + ' ' + details.payer.email_address + ' ' + details.purchase_units[0].amount.currency_code + details.purchase_units[0].amount.value + ' ' +  details.purchase_units[0].shipping.address.address_line_1);



      });


    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the client_id in the url to be public?

Comment: yes, all sandbox settings of course